# How to handle hours in date

Tags: c#

I am trying to get number of batches passed deadline, and number of batches near deadline (2 hours before the deadline). Following can get me if I am one day behind deadline. But how to handle hours?

#### What is required?

Get number of batches passed deadline, and number of batches near deadline (2 hours before the deadline

#### Customers Table:

```
CustomerID;CustomerName;BatchDeadline 
1;AAA;1
2;BBB;2
3;CCC;2
4;DDD;3
```

*BatchDeadline: Number of days after BatchDate, if 2 means second day of BatchDate in Batches table.

#### Batches Table:

```
BatchID;CustomerID;BatchDate
1;1;2014-12-10 8:00
2;2;2014-12-10 8:10
3;2;2014-12-11 10:20
4;1;2014-12-12 11:10
5;3;2014-12-12 11:12
6;3;2014-12-12 11:22
7;3;2014-12-12 11:23
```

#### Code:

```
int passedDeadline = 0;
int nearDeadline = 0;

foreach(customer c in customers)
{
  foreach(Batch b in batches) 
  {
      if (b.BatchDate < b.BatchDate(c.BatchDeadline * -1)
            passedDeadline++;
  }
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem? why do you think it doesn't work? debug your code before asking.

Comment: First of all you should decide - what language are you using. In tags you've mentioned Java, C# and VB.Net. From your code - it is definitely not VB.Net.

Comment: Also, you should state whats the error/behavior you have with your code and what you'd expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current time (don't get it in the loop as the current time changes all the time):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

Calculate the points in time that you want to compare with:

```
DateTime deadline = b.BatchDate.AddDays(c.BatchDate);
DateTime nearDeadline = deadline.AddHours(-2);
```

Now just compare the time from the table to the points in time:

```
if (now > deadline) {
  // passed the deadline
} else if (now >= nearDeadline) {
  // near the deadline
}
```